# SWIG: How to typemap the return value based on the original return value?

Tags: swig

Here's a very simple C function:

```
bool GetSomething(string* result)
```

After calling this function, the return value should indicate if the `result` holds the needed information, and user can check the return value to handle accordingly.

To SWIG this function to be used in Python code, I use the default `typemaps.i` file and then changed the function to

```
bool GetSomething(string* OUTPUT)
```

This works but still cumbersome. I'll have to do this to get the result I want:

```
success, result = GetSomething()
if success:
    # handle result
else:
    # throw exception
```

Ideally I'd like to have this interface instead:

```
result = GetSomething()
if result:
    # handle result
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you throw an exception if the function fails, so you can use `string GetSomething()`.

Comment: @MasterMind This is an exception free C++ codebase which I'm not allowed to change.

Comment: You don't have to throw the exception in C++, just in the SWIG wrapper so it becomes a Python exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example .i file of the idea mentioned in comments.  Convert a successful return status to `None` and a failing return status to an exception in Python, and append output parameters to the return value.  This requires no changes to the C++ code base:

```
%module x

%include <exception.i>

// convert non-zero int return values to exceptions
%typemap(out) int %{
    if($1)
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError,"non-zero return value");
    $result = Py_None;
    Py_INCREF(Py_None); // Py_None is a singleton so increment its reference if used.
%}

// Easy way for int*, but customize below for more complicated types
// %apply int* OUTPUT {int*};

// suppress the output parameter as an input.
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) int* (int tmp) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
%}

// append int* output parameters to the return value.
%typemap(argout) int* {
    PyObject* tmp = PyLong_FromLong(*$1);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,tmp);
}

// %inline declares and exposes a function
%inline %{
    int func(int val, int* pOut)
    {
        if(val < 1)
            return 1;
        *pOut = 2 * val;
        return 0;
    }
%}
```

If you SWIG this .i with `swig -python -c++ x.i` and compile the result into a Python extension:

```
>>> import x
>>> x.func(2)
4
>>> x.func(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: non-zero return value
```

Answer (score 0):

My current hack, hope this helps someone.

```
%{
 #define GetSomething 1
%}

%typemap(out) bool %{
#if $symname == 1
if (result) {
return Py_FromString(arg0->data());
} else {
return Py_None;
}
#endif
%}
```